# How can I prevent Google Slides embed in an iframe to scroll the parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I have the following iframe in a page (actual presentation is just an example):

```
<div id="google-slides-iframe-container">
    <iframe id="google-slides-iframe" src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1_zfj0xr6bOTZcGOPR4ASOVCccg5zvDrGrU3XxUUe5Ik/embed" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

The problem is when the presentation is not fully in view, that is, let's say the user has scrolled the page down so that half of the presentation is visible, when the user clicks the buttons to go to the next slide, the page suddenly shifts up and scrolls so that top of the presentation is now in view. Then the user has to scroll back down to reach the buttons again to go to next slide. This isn't a problem with big screens where the presentation fully fits on a page, but on smaller screens, this behavior is problematic.

How can I prevent the Google Slides document inside the iframe to scroll its parents up after clicking next and previous buttons? I did some research today, but was not successful at all. There are very hacky ways to do this, for example, tracking the mouse, keeping track of when it enters and leaves the iframe, and disabling scrolling on the page when the mouse is inside the iframe area. But that whole logic breaks down on tablets for example, when the user only uses touch gestures to interact with the page.

I'm not sure if Google is using the [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) API to achieve this. If they are, maybe it makes sense to override the prototype for this function to disable it altogether. I tried doing this on iframe and its container, but it didn't have much effect.  Maybe it also makes sense to similarly override `scrollTop()` function. I haven't tried this one yet.

[Apparently](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-permissions-policy/issues/171), this issue was raised five years ago with W3C, and they are yet to respond to it. So I couldn't find an official way to prevent iframes from scrolling their parents.

Comment: _"[...] to override the prototype for this function to disable it altogether. I tried doing this on iframe and its container, but it didn't have much effect."_ - you could override it within the context of _your_ page - but not for the context of the document loaded into the iframe, because the Same Origin Policy prevents you from accessing that to begin with here.

Comment: @CBroe that's a good point and could explain why it didn't have an affect. What else can I try?

Comment: You can not interact with the content of a document loaded from a different origin, via JavaScript. I don't think there is anything you can do here, if the Google doc scrolls _itself_ to the top - within the iframe - then that will also scroll the iframe into view within the parent document.